# Solving $ z = -i \ln\left(-ci + \sqrt{(1+c)(1-c)} \right) $ for $c$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Given,

$$ z = -i \ln\left(-ci + \sqrt{(1+c)(1-c)} \right) $$

I would like to solve for $c$. First multiply through by $i$,

$$  iz = \ln\left(-ci + \sqrt{(1+c)(1-c)} \right) .$$

Then take the exponential of both sides,

$$ e^{iz} = -ci + \sqrt{(1+c)(1-c)} $$

Not sure where to go from here, can I say

$$ \Im(e^{iz}) = \Im(-ci+\sqrt{(1+c)(1-c)}) \implies  \sin z = -c ? $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$e^{iz} +ci = \sqrt{1-c^2}\to e^{2iz}+ 2ie^{iz}c-c^2=1-c^2$$

$$e^{2iz}+ 2ie^{iz}c=1\to c=\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{2ie^{iz}}$$

Comment: Was my last step in equating the imaginary part correct?

Comment: @Dando18: it depends on the value of $c$. If $c>1$ or $c<-1$ then $\sqrt{1-c^2}$ will have an imaginary part and then your solution is not correct.

Comment: Note that $\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{2ie^{iz}} = \frac{1}{2i} (e^{-iz} - e^{iz}) = - \sin z$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert so if my final step of equating the imaginary parts was invalid, lenient upon the value of $c$, then why is the solution still correct? By chance?

Comment: @Dando18: That happens because using my final result you can conclude that $|c|=|\sin z|\le 1$ and then $\sqrt{1-c^2}\in \Bbb R$. But in your case, you should prove that before use imaginary part.

Answer (score 2):

$z=-i \log \left(\sqrt{1-c^2}-i c\right)$

derive wrt $c$

$\dfrac{dz}{dc}=-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}$

Integrate

$z=-\arcsin c + k$

$k=0$ because $c=0,\;z=0$ in the initial equation

and finally
$c=-\sin z$